# insert javascript only on page postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm sure this is fairly straightforward but i'm having trouble getting it to work. I want to add a javascript function to my page, but only when the page postsback.

So I have a button that calls some server-side code, and when it is finished and the page is re-loading I want the javascript function to be called.

Thinking about this i guess I could just add a hidden variable and set it when the button is clicked, but i think i'd rather just insert the javascript onto the page when it is loading back.

Is this possible, or even a good way to do it?

Thanks,
Neil

Edit: Okay this is my OnClick method in the C# code.

```
protected void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('hello world');</script>"); 
    EnforcementMatch(false);
    EnforcementMatch(true);
    ApplicationNotMatch();
    ApplicationMatch();
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
}
```

Another Edit: Just realised that the response.redirect at the bottom reloads my page cancelling out the code I put in, duh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx

If you place it on the button click event, you don't have to worry if it's a postback or not.

Comment: I also tried this (on the server-side click event), the javascript doesn't appear on the page. Is this not called after the page has been rendered?

Comment: @Neil - It should appear, you have to be careful how you use the method. Double check your Javascript, see if you have the script tags (as in the MSDN example), and if you still have problems update your question and show us the code you're using.

Answer (score 2):

You know about the `IsPostBack` function, right?

[IsPostBack (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx)

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock()
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thats the first thing I tried, but the javascript doesn't appear on the page. I also tried putting it in the Init, PreRender etc. events.

Answer (score 1):

This script will be fired with every single postback from updatepanel

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); 
    prm.add_endRequest(function ()    {
        alert('hello world');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place it in a separate script block, only to be rendered on postback.

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server" visible="<%#this.IsPostBack %>">
    TheCode();
</script>
```

Comment: Which browsers support the visible attribute on the script tag?  Doesn't seem to be mentioned in the W3C docs http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp

Comment: No, it's nothing a browser will ever see. If you put runat="server" in any html tag, asp.net will turn it from ordinary text into an actual Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl. And the 'visible' property indicates whether the control must be rendered in the page. So if visible="false" this tag won't be in the page the browser receives.

Comment: When I add the runat="server" attribute I cannot write javascript code between the <script> tags. I get a complie error saying "Method must have a return type"`<script type="text/javascript" runat="server" visible="<%#this.IsPostBack %>">
            alert("123");
            
        </script>`

Comment: Indeed, I forgot, script-tags are an exception to the runat="server" rule, because you can use them to add .NET code in the markup (but please, don't ever). Forget I said anything :)